# Windows Service Choose User or System Account on Install

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

When installing a windows service, is there a way to let the user installing choose between a specific user account and a computer account, such as LocalSystem?  I see how to do this at build time through service installer properties, but not during install.

Comment: what are you installing with?  MSI's? Command Line?

Comment: I will probably using a custom installer and invoke installutil.  I've seen cases where this is done, but I'm not sure how it works.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

@Doobi, @Eric, in my experience (Win7Home 64-bit, VS2010Express, not on a domain)

```
 processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalService;
 processInstaller.Username = null;
 processInstaller.Password = null;
```

will install the service as LocalService without a password prompt.

To install the service as a local user account (and provide a password prompt to enable the user to supply the credentials) I had to use:

```
 this.serviceProcessInstaller.Account =System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User;
 this.serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;
 this.serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
```

The important step I had to take to get the service installed is to put the computer name in the credentials dialog box, ie `MYPC\dave` instead of `dave`. I was surprised that I'd have to do this as it's not on a domain. I've added this comment as no other posts I've seen about this mention having to prefix the username with the PC name.

Comment: Thanks the computername\username hint fixed my issue

Comment: domain name in front of username also fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: @FabianKöbel I get an exception ' The server was not found or was not accessible. ' if I use my domain. By anychance you know what's happening?

Comment: which domain do u use? please make sure that you can establish a network connection to the server

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is, it's on the process installer. I think in the newer frameworks it's a visible property if you select the process installer on the design surface. The last time I did it (.NET 2.0) you have to add something similar to this to the *.designer.cs file:

```
 processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalService;
 processInstaller.Username = null;
 processInstaller.Password = null;
```

Comment: So how does this " let the user installing choose between a specific user account and a computer account, such as LocalSystem"

Comment: Because if you set it to a "ServiceAccount.User" and don't specify the credentials it prompts the user for credentials when you install.

Comment: @Doobi, Based on your comment, wouldn't you rather need this line of code? `processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.User;`

Answer (score 3):

Adding to previous answers, don't forget to append Machine name to Username while entering "Username" Field of password prompt. Otherwise service will not accept the credentials although if you give correct username and pwd. It will keep on pop up prompt to enter credentials. It took me one day to figure out this. Thanks to Badgerspot!