# Get ServiceProcessinstaller Account in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a C# Windows Service and a Windows Form project that is in charge of the installation of the service.

In my Windows Service right now I have my `serviceProcessInstaller` **Account** set to:

[image]

In my Windows Form project, I need a way to get the **Account** Type or to set the **Account** type of my service before installing it. The problem is that I only have access to the `.exe` service file because there is no reference between projects and that's the way to be.

I'm using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
```

to install the service.

Can I use reflection in order to get the .exe file and read that properties?
In case I can read that property, can I set those settings while installing the service using `System.Diagnostics.Process`?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453646/windows-service-choose-user-or-system-account-on-install?rq=1

Comment: That's easy when you do it directly in the service installer, but I need to get that setting by reflection or whatever so I can tell Diagnostics.Process what do to in the installation of the service.